# Do we need to make a field 'volatile', if Thread1 enters sync block, updates it, is still inside the sync block, Thread2 outside of sync reads field?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, volatile

Let's say we have 'class A' which has a data member 'var'.

```
class A
{
  int var;

method()
{
read(var);

synchronized block
{

update var here;

}

}
```

Let's say Thread 1 acquires the lock and enters the synchronized block. It updates the field value 'var'. Let's say the field value is cached in the processor's core by the Thread. It updates the value in the cache.

Now thread 2 starts running, enters method(), and reads field value 'var'.

Wil thread 2, surely get the updated value? Does synchronize makes sure thread 2 will get updated value even when Thread 1 has not exited Synchronized. In this case, do we need to make 'var' volatile?

PS - Everything is happening on the same object.

Answer (score 1):

If you would not make 'var' volatile, then there is no happens-before edge between writing and reading 'var'. So you have a data race on your hands and weird things can happen like the compiler messing things up.

So in short: make it volatile (or make sure you read 'var' using the same lock).

Answer (score 1):

> Does synchronize makes sure thread 2 will get updated value

No. `synchronized` doesn't do anything for a thread if the thread does not enter a `synchronized` block. The way to think about `synchronized` is this:  Whatever one thread does before it leaves a synchronized block is guaranteed to become visible to some other thread by the time the second thread *subsequently** enters a block that is `synchronized` on the same lock object.

For a single `int` variable, you could make it `volatile` instead. `volatile` makes a guarantee similar to the guarantee of `synchronized`: Whatever one thread does before it updates a `volatile` variable is guaranteed to become visible to some other thread by the time the second thread *subsequently** reads the same `volatile` variable.

---

* Edit: I added "subsequently" to make it clear that neither `synchronized` nor `volatile` is sufficient to ensure that the threads will access `var` in some particular order. If you wish to ensure that thread 2 will not try to read `var` until *after* thread 1 has assigned it, then you will have to use some other means† to coordinate their activity. Correct use of `synchronized` or `volatile` only can ensure that **IF** thread 1 updates `var` before thread 2 examines it, then thread 2 will see the update.

† There are many "other means." One example is a `Semaphore`. Thread 1 could `release()` a permit to the semaphore after it updates `var`, and thread 2 could `acquire()` the permit before it reads `var`. The `acquire()` call would cause thread 2 to wait if it arrived at the semaphore before thread 1 had done its job.

Comment: Nitpicking: reads and writes can be skewed (do not need to respect the real-time order) with sequential consistency. If the real-time order is important, linearizability is needed. From a practical point of view, reads/writes can't be buffered indefinitely, so to some extent, the real-time order will roughly be preserved.

Comment: @pveentjer, I don't understand how "real-time order" applies to my two rules of thumb, which basically are concrete descriptions of the "happens before" edges created by `synchronized` and by `volatile`. I'm only describing _one_ "edge." But, you inspired me to add somewhat to my answer. Does the new addition address your concern?

Comment: 'to become visible to some other thread by the time the second thread subsequently* reads the same volatile variable'. You are referring to time. So the above phrasing implies that requests are respecting the real-time order.

Comment: Imagine you would be able to hook external measuring equipment to the CPU and would be able to measure the exact timings of every operation. And thread1 would perform a store at (wallclock) time=t0+1 followed by another store at time=t0+2. If thread2 would perform a load at t0+3, then with sequential consistency this load isn't only allowed to see the load at t0+2, but also t0+1 because the real-time order doesn't need to be preserved.

Comment: So happening before doesn't imply happens-before and happens-before doesn't imply happening before. 
https://preshing.com/20130702/the-happens-before-relation/

Comment: @pveentjer, but it's not just loads and stores. We're either talking about a `volatile` variable, or we're talking about access from within `synchronized` blocks. Either way, there will be loads and stores _and memory barriers._ How does the Java Language Spec allow thread2 from your example to see the older value \*IF\* the the variable is `volatile` or \*IF\* the threads only access the variable within `synchronized(o)` blocks for the same object `o`?

Comment: A memory barrier is just an implementation detail and not part of the specification. Therefore it is best to leave it out of the discussion. The JMM is very clear about what a load is allowed to see: either the most recent write before it in happens-before order or a write it is a data race with (so not ordered by the happens-before order). But the happens-before order doesn't need to be consistent with the real-time order. A correctly synchronized program only has sequential consistency executions and is free of data races and sequential consistency doesn't care about the real-time order.

Comment: If the real-time order needs to be preserved you need Linearizability (sequential consistency + real-time order), which isn't guaranteed by the JMM. JMM is defined in terms of sequential consistency.

Comment: Example of violating the real-time order: If a thread on one CPU would issue only a single (volatile) store (so no need for fences), then this store doesn't need to be seen immediately by another CPU. First, the store is executed and the write is put in the storebuffer but the store is still speculative until it retires. But at this point the store doesn't need to be visible yet; it is still in the storebuffer. Only when the store leaves the storebuffer and is committed to the cache, the store becomes visible. So there is a period where the store is retired and becomes visible to another CPU.

Comment: @pveentjer, If what you say is true, then it is impossible to write thread-safe code in Java. Consider that if thread A periodically updates some complex, linked data structure, and thread B periodically tries to traverse it; then the values that thread B sees for some links in any given attempt could be out-of-date with respect to other links. That's similar to what plagued a project I was working on back in the 1990s. It was a nightmare to diagnose. The ultimate cause was a hardware bug that, once in a blue moon, allowed a dirty cache line to be invalidated without first being flushed.

Comment: Sequential consistency is still a very strong guarantee. Keep in mind that loads/stores can't be skewed indefinitely on the CPU. So in practice, the CPU will have some upper bound on the skewness.

Comment: "some upper bound" isn't sufficient. Any "skewness" at all in a linked data structure could be enough to segfault the JVM.

Comment: Please check the definitions of sequential consistency and linearizability and the jmm that refers to sequential consistency and you will see that reads and writes can be skewed as long is program order isn't (visibly) violated.

Comment: Check this for any easy to understand description of linearizability and sequential consistency. https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/linearizable